# how to set time format in symfony ProjectConfiguration.class.php?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

here my conversion:

```
function add_date($givendate,$hr=2)
{
    $cd = strtotime($givendate);
    $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(date('h',$cd)+$hr, date('i',$cd), date('s',$cd), date('m',$cd), date('d',$cd), date('Y',$cd)));
    return $newdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_default_timezone

Default timezone is in settings

Comment: i have it as Africa/Johannesburg, which is correct, i live in south africa, but the time needs to be a 24hr clock not 12 so 2 o'clock in the afternoon must show as 14h00 not 02h00 and 4 o'clock as 16h00 :)

Comment: I have just looked in lots of places (php.net / SO / google) and it seems you cant ... the default for the Africa/Johannesburg timezone is 12 hours format - you need to format everytime !

Comment: aaaargh i am doing it like this at the moment..its a pain in the butt! just thought i can set it once somewhere, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the default user culture in `settings.yml`:

```
default_culture:        af  # or maybe af-ZA
default_timezone:       Africa/Johannesburg
```

You may need to restart your session (clear cookies) before this settings takes into effect at your session.

Answer (score -1):

For 12 Hour Format

```
return date("g:i a", strtotime("13:30:30"))
```

Which returns 1:30 pm

For 24 Hour Format

```
return date("H:i:s", strtotime("1:30 pm"))
```

Which returns 13:30:00

Comment: i am doing it like this at the moment: please see top